Can I safely remove older *patch* versions of the .NET runtime?
I'm aware that you can install multiple versions of the .NET runtime side-by-side, and that you may well need to do this if apps you use require different versions. But is there a reason to keep multiple patch versions of the same minor version of the runtime? Will an app ever specify a particular patch version, and not accept a later one? Or do they only specify as far as a particular minor version?
I ask because I have Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.20 and Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.28 both installed. Some security scanning software is flagging v6.0.20 as vulnerable. If I uninstall it, will any application that used it be fine to use v6.0.28?

So uninstall Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.20 but neither Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.20 nor Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.28 but you have two minor versions of the same major version,  You should uninstall both of them and instead install 6.0.33 if you want to be "current" and"secure"

Yes, almost all .NET apps target a minor version and automatically roll forward to run on the latest installed patch, so there's no reason to keep old patches installed since they won't be used. Only apps with RollForward=Disable (not recommended) would break. .NET installers (like EXE files) try to autoremove old patch versions, except dotnet-install.sh leaves old patch versions behind that I manually delete.
